# mysql,perl, download csv from mysql table

Tags: mysql, perl

I have this script in perl and it crashes. The database is probably million rows. How can I do this? Thanks

```
sub MYSQL_CREATE_CSV
{
    my ($dbh, $tablename, $csvname) = @_;
    my $mysql_tablename = $dbh->quote_identifier($tablename);

    print "[INFO] EXTRACTING INFO FROM TABLE : $mysql_tablename\n";
    my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare(qq|SELECT * FROM $mysql_tablename | );
    $sth1->execute(  );

    open (FILE, ">$csvname") or die "[ERROR] $0 - cannot write to file : $! \n";
    #   EXTRACT COLUMN NAME
    my @COLUMNNAME = @{$sth1->{NAME}};
    my $temp = join (",",@COLUMNNAME);
    print FILE $temp , "\n";
    while ( my @row = $sth1->fetchrow_array(  ) )
    {
        my $temp = join(",",@row);
        print FILE $temp . "\n";
    }
    close FILE;

    print "[INFO] \t\tCREATING FILE : $csvname \n" if (-e $csvname);
}
```

Comment: What is the error when perl crashes?

Comment: something about running out of memory at $sth1->execute(  );
 line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this line **before** `$dbh->prepare()`

```
$dbh->{'mysql_use_result'} = 1;
```

This will tell MySQL do not load whole result in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Skip all the perl and dump it directly:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

It won't include the column names as such but you can tweak the query to add them.